# What are the components of the Mel mfcc

Tags: librosa, mfcc

In looking at the output of this line of code:

```
mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=librosa_audio, sr=librosa_sample_rate, n_mfcc=40)
print("MFCC Shape = ", mfccs.shape)
```

I get a response of `MFCC Shape = (40,1876)`.  What do these two numbers represent?  I looked at the [librosa website](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.feature.mfcc.html) but still could not decipher what are these two values.

Any insights will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first dimension (40) is the number of MFCC *coefficients*, and the second dimensions (1876) is the number of time frames. The number of MFCC is specified by `n_mfcc`, and the number of time frames is given by the length of the audio (in samples) divided by the `hop_length`.

To understand the meaning of the MFCCs themselves, you should understand the steps it takes to compute them:

- Spectrograms, using the [Short-Time-Fourier-Transform (STFT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform)
- The Mel spectrogram, from applying [Mel scale filterbanks](https://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/doc/HTKBook21/node54.html) to the STFT
- Mel Frequency *Cepstral Coefficients*, from applying the [DCT transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform) on the mel-spectrogram.

A good written explainer is [Haytham Fayek: Speech Processing for Machine Learning: Filter banks, Mel-Frequency Cepstral Coefficients (MFCCs) and What's In-Between](https://haythamfayek.com/2016/04/21/speech-processing-for-machine-learning.html)
and a good video explainer is [The Sound of AI: Mel-Frequency Cepstral Coefficients Explained Easily](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_SH2nfbQZ8).